# Strategy/Pattern to bypass a super() constructor

Tags: java, constructor, design-patterns, superclass

it's me again with my legacy Java App. I have a core class that handles a lot of the important logic in the App. Let's called it MyManager. MyManager inherits from a class in a library, let's call it TopManager. The constraint is you can't modify any of these definition.

```
public class MyManager extends TopManager {

    public MyManager(String a, String b){ 
        super(a);
        initialize(b);
    }

    public MyManager(){
        this(null,null);
    }

    private void initialize(String b){
        //specific implementation
    }
}

public class TopManager {
    public TopManager(String s){ 
        //some implementation
    } 
}
```

I want to create a class CustomManager who have all the MyManager features but using TopManager default constructor.

```
public class CustomManager extends MyManager
    public CustomManager(){

     //super(); NO should call TopManager constructor
    }
```

Since it's not possible in Java, I am looking for other bright ideas

Comment: make a argument constructor , but dont do anything in it , it can act as default constructor

Comment: @greedybuddha `super(String, String)` calls `TopManager(String)`.

Comment: I can't see that `TopManager` has a default constructor.

Comment: the constructor without parameters actually calls this(null). Didn't had all the code to keep on the topic (inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a class CustomManager who have all the MyManager
>   features

yes, using **composition**

> but using `TopManager` default constructor.

by using **generalization**

```
class CustomManager extends TopManager { // have all properties of TopManager

  private MyManager myManager; // have all behaviours of MyManager by delegating the call

}
```

Comment: its HAS-A thing and not IS-A

Comment: The problem is that you won't be able to call `myManager.initialize(String)` as it is a private method.

Comment: a private method anyways cannot be invoked, even if you extend the class. So no issues there.

Comment: @eternay the op is trying *not* to call `myManager.initialize(String)` :)

Comment: that's a begining on where to go. Yes it's he initialize() part that do evil stuff and shouldn't be in the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CustomManager` should inherit from `TopManager` instead of `MyManager`.

Comment: Incorrect. `CustomManager` needs to have the features present in `MyManager`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason that it is not possible in java. If you manage to bypass calling constructor of your direct super class you actually create invalid instance. Instance of `CustomManager` is `MyManager` too. If constructor of `MyManager` was not called it is not initialized.

This means that you cannot bypass it without reporting to `MyMaanger` that you want to do this. What does it mean "reporting"? This means that `MyMaanger` should know that you want to bypass its normal initization. You can do it by exposing constructor with special boolean flag that indicates whether you need or need not normal initialization:

```
public class MyManager extends TopManager {
    public MyManager(boolean skipInit) {
        this(false);
    }
    protected MyManager(boolean skipInit) {
        super();
        if(skipInit) {
            return;
        }
        // init
    }
}

public class CustomManager extends MyManager {
     CustomManager() {
        super(true);
     } 
}
```

Comment: But he cannot change TopManager's and MyManager's code, as I understood the op.

Answer (score 1):

If the stars are right, you may be able to use composition instead of inheritance. Extend `TopManager` and instantiate a `MyManager` for internal use. You'll be able to acess package-private members if you define the class in the same package. That's the same level of access you'd have when extending `MyManager`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for other bright ideas

Have you considered using something like [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/)?

This is rather rough idea but I know that it can do some wicked magic related to code generation/modifying classes at run/load-time (often used in mocking/dynamic aop implementations).

I know that my suggestion is rather hackery, but it seems that it might be handy for you once cornered by that legacy lib you mention...